# Drag and Replace DIV in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to do DRAG and REPLACE div in javascript. For Ex: I am having 2 Div's. If i drag the 2nd Div and place it on the 1st Div, automatically the 1st div should be replaced to the 2nd position. The code which i am having now is overlapping..

my aspx page..

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="info">
        Start drag process...</div>
    <div id="square" style="position: relative; width: 60px; height: 60px; background: #990033;
        border: 2px solid #3399CC;">
    </div>
      <div id="Div1" style="position: relative; width: 60px; height: 60px; background: #efe;
        border: 2px solid #3399CC;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var square = DragHandler.attach(document.getElementById('square'));

        var Div1 = DragHandler.attach(document.getElementById('Div1'));


    </script>
</div>
```

my js file...

```
/**
```

*
*  Crossbrowser Drag Handler
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var DragHandler = {

```
// private property.
_oElem : null,


// public method. Attach drag handler to an element.
attach : function(oElem) {
    oElem.onmousedown = DragHandler._dragBegin;

    // callbacks
    oElem.dragBegin = new Function();
    oElem.drag = new Function();
    oElem.dragEnd = new Function();

    return oElem;
},


// private method. Begin drag process.
_dragBegin : function(e) {
    var oElem = DragHandler._oElem = this;

    if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.left))) { oElem.style.left = '0px'; }
    if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.top))) { oElem.style.top = '0px'; }

    var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

    e = e ? e : window.event;
    oElem.mouseX = e.clientX;
    oElem.mouseY = e.clientY;

    oElem.dragBegin(oElem, x, y);

    document.onmousemove = DragHandler._drag;
    document.onmouseup = DragHandler._dragEnd;
    return false;
},


// private method. Drag (move) element.
_drag : function(e) {
    var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;

    var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

    e = e ? e : window.event;
    oElem.style.left = x + (e.clientX - oElem.mouseX) + 'px';
    oElem.style.top = y + (e.clientY - oElem.mouseY) + 'px';

    oElem.mouseX = e.clientX;
    oElem.mouseY = e.clientY;

    oElem.drag(oElem, x, y);

    return false;
},


// private method. Stop drag process.
_dragEnd : function() {
    var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;

    var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

    oElem.dragEnd(oElem, x, y);

    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    DragHandler._oElem = null;
}
```

}

How to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recognition part:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("draggable").length; i++) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("draggable")[i];

    if (elem != oElem) {

        if (oElem.offsetTop + parseInt(oElem.style.height) > elem.offsetTop
           && oElem.offsetTop < elem.offsetTop + parseInt(elem.style.height)) {
            if (oElem.offsetLeft + parseInt(oElem.style.width) > elem.offsetLeft
               && oElem.offsetLeft < elem.offsetLeft + parseInt(elem.style.width)) {
                alert("overlapping");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your div's need to have a "draggable" class.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DqJrV/

Comment: Could you create a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ for us ?
Edit: Nevermind already created one, I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes, what was in the demo, the samething happens for me...I jus want to replace the div..

Comment: There you go I added the overlapping recognition for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DqJrV/ If you want to replace it, just asign the dragged element the position values of the other element.

Comment: `element.style.left` or `element.offsetLeft`. If you use the first one, use `parseInt()` with it.  Because `style.left` returns a string with "px" at the end.